# Can't define runtime for 2 functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

[image: Click here to check question image]

Hello, I have 2 functions in the image. And the question is about getting their runtime.

The answer for EX4 function is O(n^2) and EX5 is O(n^4).
I don't get this.

**Question for EX4:**

we have inner loop that starts with j=0 to i. From my perspective, this is equivalent to "1+2+...+n", so is "n(n+1)/2", therefore, O(n^2) for inner loop only.
However, we also know that outer loop runs from i=0 to n, which is O(n). So the answer I thought for EX4 was actually "O(n) * O(n^2) = O(n^3)". But the real answer says O(n^2). Why is that?

**Question for EX5:**

Similarly, I thought it is "n*(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)" for inner loop and also "n*n=O(n^2)" for outer loop, so the whole runtime become O(n^2) * O(n^2) = O(n^4), which is same as real answer of this question. But if I justify this in this way, then my solution to EX4 doesn't make sense. Why is it O(n^4) specifically?

Comment: Ex5(n) = Ex4(n^2). So if you can calculate the runtime of Ex4 as a function of its input, say f(n), then you immediately have the runtime of Ex5, namely f(n^2).

Comment: Ex 4: "1+2+...+n" is the number of times the inner loop executes **in total**, why would you multiply that by `n` at the end?

Comment: Ex 5: The inner loop executes `1+2+...+x = x(x+1)/2` times, where x is n^2, which directly leads you to O(n^4) (also with no multiplication like you did in ex 4).